# Code compiles, but "percentage complete" during compilation doesn't change

Tags: c++, cmake

I have some C++ code with two source files and a header file. When compiling with 'make' a week or two ago, it would spit out [33%], [66%], and [100%] as it compiled/linked/etc each file, but for some unknown reason, it's now saying [33%] at each of the three steps. Any idea what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: what OS, Windows, linux, macOs? this q&a on the unix&linux site might be helpful or related [What could be causing make to hang when compiling on multiple cores?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/what-could-be-causing-make-to-hang-when-compiling-on-multiple-cores)

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: My guess that you perform a **parallel build** (e.g. your `make` has a default `-j4` parameter). With parallel build percentage may be wrong. But that doesn't affect on the build's correctness. Again, without the code it is impossible to say anything with confident.